# Using query flatten function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten

I am trying to convert my original data format from this:

***Original data table***
[image]

To this:

***Desired outcome***

[image]

I tried copying the formula I found in this forum, but somehow the result doesn't come out right.

Attached is the sample sheet, which hopefully explains my issue better.

[Sample_Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_Wm4lz6CG95_0gRkgs5KIwfS8NDqdC43vxzCyACNis/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(rep_,data!C6:C, grp_,data!J6:AR, header_,data!J5:AR5, size_,5,
 Σ,reduce(wraprows(,columns(rep_)+1+size_,),sequence(columns(grp_)/size_,1,1,size_),lambda(a,c,{a;{rep_,wrapcols(index(header_,c),rows(rep_),index(header_,c)),choosecols(grp_,sequence(size_,1,c))}})),
 Λ,filter(Σ,index(Σ,,1)<>""),sort(Λ,xmatch(index(Λ,,1),index(rep_,,1)),1))
```

[image]

***Alternate formula:***

```js
=let(Σ,data!C6:C,
     Λ,vstack(hstack(Σ,wrapcols(data!J5,rows(Σ),data!J5),data!J6:N),
              hstack(Σ,wrapcols(data!O5,rows(Σ),data!O5),data!O6:S),
              hstack(Σ,wrapcols(data!T5,rows(Σ),data!T5),data!T6:X),
              hstack(Σ,wrapcols(data!Y5,rows(Σ),data!Y5),data!Y6:AC),
              hstack(Σ,wrapcols(data!AD5,rows(Σ),data!AD5),data!AD6:AH),
              hstack(Σ,wrapcols(data!AI5,rows(Σ),data!AI5),data!AI6:AM),
              hstack(Σ,wrapcols(data!AN5,rows(Σ),data!AN5),data!AN6:AR)),
       sort(filter(Λ,index(Λ,,1)<>""),1,1))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this.  If I am to add 2 more columns in the original table of the Sample Data tab, what should I change to keep the formula working?  I did try to add 2 columns, and suddenly the formula is no longer working.

Comment: Please recreate that in your test sheet & I can check it out. Also color code the newly added columns that is causing the formula to break

Comment: I added the 2 columns in the original table, and put your solution in the tab called New Formula.  Since I added the columns, your formula is giving incorrect results.  But if I deleted the new 2 columns, it works perfectly.

Comment: Updated the formula in your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_Wm4lz6CG95_0gRkgs5KIwfS8NDqdC43vxzCyACNis/edit#gid=1861544603). Added alternate formula as well...